# Minecraft Launcher stuck in restart loop

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

When I click play on the Minecraft launcher while I am on my Forge profile, it will begin to load but then it will reset itself repeatedly. What can I do to fix this?

I also have mods and none are from the 1.7.8 or higher, all are from 1.7.2 or lower. I went to the dev console and it said this:

```
[19:11:42 ERROR]: Game ended with bad state (exit code 1)
[19:11:42 INFO]: Ignoring visibility rule and showing launcher due to a game crash
[19:11:42 INFO]: Deleting C:\Users\Christopher\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.7.2-Forge10.12.1.1061\1.7.2-Forge10.12.1.1061-natives-451559628533801
```

What can I do?

Comment: That's the launcher output. We need the game's crash log.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your java is up to date:

https://www.java.com/en/download/

Your mods should all be 1.7.2, there should be none from any other game version.

Comment: Even then, it still doesn't work. It was working fine without any mods yesterday, then i downloaded some and it was still fine. Last night i added more mods and it stopped working, I thought that might be the problem so i took them out the Mods folder and still it wont work.

Answer (score -1):

**Things that may help**

Update your java, latest version can be found here: https://java.com/en

Redownload Minecraft.exe, download can be found here: https://minecraft.net/download